# Is it possible to use AKAmplitudeTracker on AKAudioPlayer and measure the amplitude changes?

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

Hey I am working on a project(which is in swift) and it compares two audio signals and measure the correctness. **AUDIOKIT** pod is used to convert the audio from microphone(AKAmplitudeTracker) to float numbers. I am trying to implement the same method by applying the tracker on the AKAudioPlayer. What I am trying to do is performing sampling on the source signal and the reference signal and get it as amplitude data only, and then performing **DTW(Dynamic time warping)** algorithm.

Is there any means by which I can get the AKAudioPlayer music to be converted as amplitude data? Is it possible to add a tracker to the AKAudioPlayer currently playing music? Codes are given below. I need some expert advices, Thanks in advance and Happy coding.

```
//
//  Conductor.swift
//  AmplitudeTracker
//
//  Created by Mark Jeschke on 10/3/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Mark Jeschke. All rights reserved.
//

import AudioKit
import AudioKitUI

// Treat the conductor like a manager for the audio engine.
class Conductor {

// Singleton of the Conductor class to avoid multiple instances of the audio engine

var url:URL?
var fileName:String?
var type:String?

static let sharedInstance = Conductor()
var isPlayingKit:Bool?

var micTracker: AKAmplitudeTracker!
var mp3Tracker: AKAmplitudeTracker!

var player:AKAudioPlayer!
var mic: AKMicrophone!

var delay: AKDelay!
var reverb: AKCostelloReverb!

// Balance between the delay and reverb mix.
var reverbAmountMixer = AKDryWetMixer()

func play(file: String, type: String) -> AKAudioPlayer? {

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: file, withExtension: type)
    let file = try! AKAudioFile(forReading: url!)
    player = try! AKAudioPlayer(file: file)

    if self.isPlayingKit! {
        player.play()
        mp3Tracker = AKAmplitudeTracker(player)
        delay = AKDelay(mp3Tracker)
        delay.time = 0.0
        delay.feedback = 0.0
        delay.dryWetMix = 0.5
        reverb = AKCostelloReverb(delay)
        reverb.presetShortTailCostelloReverb()
        reverbAmountMixer = AKDryWetMixer(delay, reverb, balance: 0.8)
        AudioKit.output = reverbAmountMixer
    }
    else {
        self.isPlayingKit = true
        AudioKit.output = nil
        player.stop()
    }
    return player
}

init() {
    AKSettings.playbackWhileMuted = true
    mic = AKMicrophone()
    print("INIT CONDUCTOR")

    micTracker = AKAmplitudeTracker(mic)
    delay = AKDelay(micTracker)
    delay.time = 0.5
    delay.feedback = 0.1
    delay.dryWetMix = 0.5
    reverb = AKCostelloReverb(delay)
    reverb.presetShortTailCostelloReverb()
    reverbAmountMixer = AKDryWetMixer(delay, reverb, balance: 0.8)
    AudioKit.output = reverbAmountMixer

    isPlayingKit = true
    startAudioEngine()
}

func startAudioEngine() {
    AudioKit.start()
    isPlayingKit = true
    print("Audio engine started")
}

func stopAudioEngine() {
    AudioKit.stop()
    isPlayingKit = false
    print("Audio engine stopped")
}
}
```

The above mentioned method captures the amplitude of the microphone.

The below given is the location where I tried to use AKAmplitudeTracker on AKAudioPlayer.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  AudioBoom
//
//  Created by Alex Babu on 20/06/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Naico. All rights reserved.
//

 import AudioKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

var instantanousAmplitudeData = [Double]()
var timer:Timer?
var timerCount:Int?
let conductor = Conductor.sharedInstance
var player:AKAudioPlayer?

@IBOutlet weak var holderView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var equalizer: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var percentageLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    timerCount = 0
    playMusicOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = playMusicOutlet.frame.size.height/2
    playMusicOutlet.layer.borderColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
    playMusicOutlet.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    playMusicOutlet.clipsToBounds = true

    musicDTW.layer.cornerRadius = musicDTW.frame.size.height/2
    musicDTW.layer.borderColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
    musicDTW.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    musicDTW.clipsToBounds = true

    holderView.layer.cornerRadius = holderView.frame.size.width/2
    holderView.clipsToBounds = true
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBOutlet weak var playMusicOutlet: UIButton!
@IBAction func playMusic(_ sender: Any) {
    playMusicOutlet.setTitle("Talk now", for: .normal)
    self.equalizer.isHidden = false
    timerCount = 0
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({(_ granted: Bool) -> Void in
        if granted {
            print("Permission granted")
            self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.05, repeats: true) { [unowned self] (timer) in
                if let count = self.timerCount {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.timerCount = count + 1
                        print("Amplitude of mic detected:\(self.conductor.micTracker.amplitude)")
                        print("Amplitude of mic counter:\(String(describing: count))")

                        print("Amplitude of mp3 detected:\(self.conductor.micTracker.amplitude)")
                        print("Amplitude of mp3 Counter:\(String(describing: count))")

                        self.instantanousAmplitudeData.append(self.conductor.micTracker.amplitude)
                        self.equalizer.frame.size.height = CGFloat(self.conductor.micTracker.amplitude * 500)
                        self.percentageLabel.text = String(Int(((self.conductor.micTracker.amplitude * 500)/500) * 100)) + "%"

                        if count == 10000 {
                            timer.invalidate()
                            self.equalizer.isHidden = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            print("Permission denied")
        }
    })
}

@IBOutlet weak var musicDTW: UIButton!
@IBAction func musicDTWAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let anotherConductor = Conductor.sharedInstance
    if let ccc = anotherConductor.play(file: "Timebomb", type: "mp3") {
        musicDTW.setTitle("Music DTW on", for: .normal)
        if let mp3Tracker = conductor.mp3Tracker {
            self.equalizer.frame.size.height = CGFloat(mp3Tracker.amplitude * 500)
        }
    }
    else {
        musicDTW.setTitle("Music DTW off", for: .normal)
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these out!
**Conductor Class**

```
import AudioKit
import AudioKitUI

// Treat the conductor like a manager for the audio engine.
class Conductor {

// Singleton of the Conductor class to avoid multiple instances of the audio engine

var url:URL?
var fileName:String?
var type:String?

static let sharedInstance = Conductor()
var isPlayingKit:Bool?

var micTracker: AKAmplitudeTracker!
var mp3Tracker: AKAmplitudeTracker!

var player:AKAudioPlayer!
var mic: AKMicrophone!

var delay: AKDelay!
var reverb: AKCostelloReverb!

// Balance between the delay and reverb mix.
var reverbAmountMixer = AKDryWetMixer()

func play(file: String, type: String) -> AKAudioPlayer? {

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: file, withExtension: type)
    let file = try! AKAudioFile(forReading: url!)
    player = try! AKAudioPlayer(file: file)

    if self.isPlayingKit! {
        mp3Tracker = AKAmplitudeTracker(player)
        delay = AKDelay(mp3Tracker)
        delay.time = 0.0
        delay.feedback = 0.0
        delay.dryWetMix = 0.5
        reverb = AKCostelloReverb(delay)
        reverb.presetShortTailCostelloReverb()
        reverbAmountMixer = AKDryWetMixer(delay, reverb, balance: 0.8)
        AudioKit.output = reverbAmountMixer      //#1
        player.play()                            //#2
    }
    else {
        self.isPlayingKit = true
        AudioKit.output = nil
//            player.stop()
        stopAudioEngine()
    }
    return player
}

func isPlayingAudioKit() -> Bool {
    return isPlayingKit!
}

init() {
    self.isPlayingKit = false
}

func initMicrophone() {
    AKSettings.playbackWhileMuted = true
    mic = AKMicrophone()
    print("INIT CONDUCTOR")

    micTracker = AKAmplitudeTracker(mic)
    delay = AKDelay(micTracker)
    delay.time = 1.5
    delay.feedback = 0.1
    delay.dryWetMix = 1.0
    reverb = AKCostelloReverb(delay)
    reverb.presetShortTailCostelloReverb()
    reverbAmountMixer = AKDryWetMixer(delay, reverb, balance: 0.5)
    AudioKit.output = reverbAmountMixer

    isPlayingKit = true
    startAudioEngine()
}

func startAudioEngine() {
    AudioKit.start()
    isPlayingKit = true
    print("Audio engine started")
}

func stopAudioEngine() {
    AudioKit.stop()
    isPlayingKit = false
    print("Audio engine stopped")
}
}
```

**ViewController**

```
import AudioKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var instantanousUserAudioData = [Float]()
var referenceAudioData = [Float]()
var timer:Timer?
var timerCount:Int?
let conductor = Conductor.sharedInstance

@IBOutlet weak var holderView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var equalizer: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var percentageLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var timerOutlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var micOutlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var DTWOutlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var musicOutlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func timerAction(_ sender: Any) {
    self.timer?.invalidate()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    timerCount = 0

    micOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = micOutlet.frame.size.height/2
    micOutlet.layer.borderColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
    micOutlet.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    micOutlet.clipsToBounds = true

    musicOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = musicOutlet.frame.size.height/2
    musicOutlet.layer.borderColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
    musicOutlet.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    musicOutlet.clipsToBounds = true

    DTWOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = DTWOutlet.frame.size.height/2
    DTWOutlet.layer.borderColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
    DTWOutlet.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    DTWOutlet.clipsToBounds = true

    timerOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = timerOutlet.frame.size.height/2
    timerOutlet.layer.borderColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
    timerOutlet.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    timerOutlet.clipsToBounds = true

    holderView.layer.cornerRadius = holderView.frame.size.width/2
    holderView.clipsToBounds = true

    self.micOutlet.isEnabled = false
    self.musicOutlet.isEnabled = false

    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({(_ granted: Bool) -> Void in
        self.micOutlet.isEnabled = granted
        self.musicOutlet.isEnabled = granted
    })
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func micAction(_ sender: Any) {

    conductor.initMicrophone()
    self.timerCount = 0
    self.equalizer.isHidden = false
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.05, repeats: true) { [unowned self] (timer) in
        if let count = self.timerCount {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.timerCount = count + 1
                print("Amplitude of mic detected:\(self.conductor.micTracker.amplitude)")
                print("Amplitude of mp3 Counter:\(String(describing: count))")

                self.instantanousUserAudioData.append(Float(self.conductor.micTracker.amplitude))
                self.equalizer.frame.size.height = CGFloat(self.conductor.micTracker.amplitude * 500)
                self.percentageLabel.text = String(Int(((self.conductor.micTracker.amplitude * 500)/500) * 100)) + "%"

                if count > 10 && self.conductor.micTracker.amplitude == 0.0 && self.instantanousUserAudioData.last == 0.0 {

                    self.micOutlet.backgroundColor = .green
                    self.micOutlet.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
                    self.micOutlet.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
                    timer.invalidate()
                }
                if count == 0 {
                    self.micOutlet.backgroundColor = .clear
                    self.micOutlet.setTitleColor(.cyan, for: .normal)
                    self.micOutlet.layer.borderColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
@IBAction func musicAction(_ sender: Any) {
    self.timerCount = 0
        if self.conductor.play(file: voiceReference, type: type_mp3) != nil {
            self.timer?.invalidate()

            self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.05, repeats: true) { [unowned self] (timer) in
                if let count = self.timerCount {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        self.timerCount = count + 1
                        print("Amplitude of mp3 detected:\(self.conductor.mp3Tracker.amplitude)")
                        print("Amplitude of mp3 Counter:\(String(describing: count))")
                        self.referenceAudioData.append(Float(self.conductor.mp3Tracker.amplitude))
                        self.equalizer.frame.size.height = CGFloat(self.conductor.mp3Tracker.amplitude * 500)
                        self.equalizer.isHidden = false
                        self.percentageLabel.text = String(Int(((self.conductor.mp3Tracker.amplitude * 500)/500) * 100)) + "%"

                        if count > 10 && self.conductor.mp3Tracker.amplitude == 0.0 && self.referenceAudioData.last == 0.0 {

                            self.musicOutlet.backgroundColor = .green
                            self.musicOutlet.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
                            self.musicOutlet.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

                            timer.invalidate()
                        }
                        if count == 0 {
                            self.musicOutlet.backgroundColor = .clear
                            self.musicOutlet.setTitleColor(.cyan, for: .normal)
                            self.musicOutlet.layer.borderColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
        }
}

@IBAction func resultAction(_ sender: Any) {
    print("mic array:\(instantanousUserAudioData)")
    print("song array:\(referenceAudioData)")
    self.timer?.invalidate()

    if referenceAudioData.count > 0, instantanousUserAudioData.count > 0 {
        let refData = knn_curve_label_pair(curve: referenceAudioData,label: "reference")
        let userData = knn_curve_label_pair(curve: instantanousUserAudioData,label: "userData")
        let attempt:KNNDTW = KNNDTW()
        attempt.train(data_sets: [refData,userData])

        let prediction: knn_certainty_label_pair = attempt.predict(curve_to_test: referenceAudioData)
        print("predicted :" + prediction.label, "with ", prediction.probability * 100,"% certainty")

        resultLabel.text = "DTW cost is " + String(attempt.dtw_cost(y: referenceAudioData, x: instantanousUserAudioData))
        print("COST OF THE DTW ALGORITHM IS : \(String(attempt.dtw_cost(y: referenceAudioData, x: instantanousUserAudioData)))")
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot going on with all this code, so its hard to debug it but what you describe is definitely possible and you probably just have some small thing wrong. Perhaps you can share the repo with me privately and I can fix it for you.